# Angular 2 - Accessing content and events from ng-content projection in child component

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I am making a sidebar in angular2.

**Code:**

Sidebar (child) component's template:

```ts
<div class="sidebar">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Parent component's template:

```ts
<app-sidebar>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapsible-1">Menu-item</a>
    <ul id="collapsible-1">
      <li>Sub-item 1</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</app-sidebar>
```

In the sidebar component, I am projecting the content written in the parent component using `<ng-content></ng-content>`.

**What I want to do:**

When I click on `Menu-item` anchor tag, I want the list to toggle (appear and disappear, as in a collapsible).

**What I have tried and The Problem:**

I kept a `(click)` event on the anchor tag. But in that case, it notifies in the parent component, and not in the child `app-sidebar` component. For re-usability purposes, I don't want functionality to be in parent component. How can I know when user clicks on the anchor tag in the `app-sidebar` component, and change the display for the list?

Is there any other way to make a reusable collapsible in the sidebar? Tell me if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a service in `app-sidebar` and inject it to items

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  providers: [MyService],
  template: `
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class Sidebar {
}
```

and make the items components or a directive that injects this service from the parent

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar-item',
  template: `
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class SidebarItem {
  constructor(myService:MyService) {
    console.log(myService);
  }
}
```

This item component then can notify the `Sidebar` component about clicks and can subscribe to notifications from `Sidebar` about for example display itself as selected.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XOQLkM2MI7rI1BOFATJU?p=preview)